# How can i achieve this design in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i achieve this mockup design in android xml layout. This is the link to my code

https://kobra.io/#/e/-KGWAyH_q8bR2GuLwZas

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DMms.png)

Comment: Have you even tried to write code?

Comment: @yes I have but i could not get the layout below the cirlcepageindicator

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use [android material design](http://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) pattern. Here is a rough idea which view components you should be using to make your layout same as VD :-**

[image]

In case you do not know what is **[FAB](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) , [cardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) or [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)** then it is good opportunity to learn material design pattern.

You can start from this [**tutorial**](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/) or try to compile [**this sample project**](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop), it contain everything you require for your design.

Good luck.